# SQL - add one more column as result of subquery? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a query which gives me perfectly good results:

```
select 
    A.ID_acc, A.ID_us, A.st, table3.KFL, 
    '100' as myattribute, 
    '101' as my attribute2
from 
    SOURCE1 as A
left join
    (select 
         table2.ID_us, table2.ID_acc, 
         CASE WHEN table2.KFL_type = 'KFL' THEN P.index_num ELSE table2.KFL_type END as KFL
     from
         (select 
              table1.ID_us, table1.ID_acc, 
              CASE WHEN sum(table1.count_kfl) > 1  THEN '9999' WHEN sum(table1.count_kfl) = 1 THEN 'KFL' END as KFL_type
         from
             (SELECT 
                  ID_us, ID_acc, count(*) as count_kfl 
              FROM 
                  payments
              WHERE
                  index_num IN (200, 201, 203) 
                  AND (date >= XXXX or date2 >= 'XXXXX') 
              GROUP BY
                  1, 2) as table1
         group by 
            1, 2) as table2 
     join 
         SOURCE2 as P on table2.ID_us = P.ID_us 
                      and table2.ID_acc = P.ID_acc
     where 
         (P.date>= XXXX or P.date2 >= 'XXXXX') 
         and index_num in (201,201,203)
     group by 
         1, 2
     order by 
         1, 2) as table3 on table3.ID_us = A.ID_us 
                         and table3.ID_acc = A.ID_acc 
where 
    A.not_deleted >= XXXXXX
```

This query is not my main question, so I only copied it just to short brief, but I wondering how I can now add one more additional column (result of count operation) as the end of my first query? Just to do not making 2 separately and then mixing results. Naturally I don't want to influence on my earlier fields results.

I have second query which looks like this:

```
select A.ID_us, count(*)/2 as number
from
 SOURCE1 as A
left join
SOURCE3 as B
on A.ID_acc = B.ID_acc
where A.date >= XXXX
group by 1
```

The link between those 2 queries is attribute ID_acc in SOURCE A which appear in first and in second query.

But don't have idea how do it?

```
select A.ID_acc, A.ID_us, A.st, table3.KFL, '100' as myattribute, '101' as my attribute2, NEWSOURCE.MYNEW_attribute
from SOURCE1 as A
left join
(
...
)
as table3 on table3.ID_us = A.ID_us and table3.ID_acc = A.ID_acc 
where A.not_deleted >= XXXXXX
left join
(
.
.
.
)
as NEWSOURCE
```

Something like this of course, don't work:///

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a correlated subquery:

```
select A.ID_acc, A.ID_us, A.st, table3.KFL, '100' as myattribute, 
'101' as my attribute2,
( select count(*)/2 as number from SOURCE1 as IA left join SOURCE3 as IB on
  IA.ID_acc = IB.ID_acc and IA.ID_Acc = A.ID_Acc where IA.date >= XXXX ) as NewColumn
 from ...
```

Note the use of new aliases in the correlated subquery.